# Is there a simple way to separate two overlapping routes in PostgreSQL into sections?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database, each contains one route, and they have some overlapping sections. I want to merge them together and to divide into separate sections based on overlapping information and route quality information (separate filed in the table).

I have tried to merge the tables, but I still don't have information about the segments.

My tables looks like this

Table1:

```
id latitude   longitude route_quality
1   47.948208   8.499215    1
2   47.948208   8.499313    1
3   47.948044   8.499697    2
4   47.948006   8.499986    2
5   47.94809    8.500163    1
6   47.948402   8.500023    1
7   47.949173   8.500094    1
8   47.949554   8.5001335   1
9   47.949623   8.500321    1
10  47.949207   8.502197    1
11  47.949104   8.5028515   1
```

Table2:

```
latitude   longitude route_quality
1    47.948208  8.499215    1
2    47.948208  8.499313    1
3    47.948044  8.499697    2
4    47.948006  8.499986    2
5    47.94809   8.500163    1
6    47.948402  8.500023    1
7    47.949173  8.500094    1
8    47.949555  8.5001336   3
9    47.949624  8.500322    3
10   47.949207  8.502197    1
11   47.949104  8.5028515   1
```

As you can see I have some overlaps and differences in route quality and I want to have something like this:

Result:

```
latitude   longitude route_quality section
47.948208   8.499215    1            1  //overlapping
47.948208   8.499313    1            1  //overlapping
47.948044   8.499697    2            2  //overlapping but different route quality starts
47.948006   8.499986    2            2  //overlapping
47.94809    8.500163    1            3  //overlapping but different route quality starts
47.948402   8.500023    1            3  //overlapping
47.949173   8.500094    1            3  //overlapping
47.949554   8.5001335   1            4  //this is from Table1
47.949623   8.500321    1            4  //this is from Table1
47.949555   8.5001336   3            5  //this is from Table2
47.949624   8.500322    3            5  //this is from Table2
47.949207   8.502197    1            6  //overlapping starts
47.949104   8.5028515   1            6  //overlapping
```

I have tried with cursors, with merge, with union, but everything was without success. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Here is an example of visually represented sections. Each color is a different section, based on route forks and route_quality field.

[Route sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azjls.png)

Thanks.

Comment: what is a section overlap? and you need add one id field so route have an order

Comment: When I have the same coordinates in both tables like this:
Table 1:

    47.948208   8.499215    1
    47.948208   8.499313    1

Table2

    47.948208   8.499215    1
    47.948208   8.499313    1

Comment: I agree with Juan: you have nothing to define the order.

Comment: I have an ID column, but it is just auto-increment value. I'll edit my question.

Comment: You need add some kind of id otherwise we dont know what order visit each locations

Comment: Where does the section number come from? How is it determined?

Comment: Section number should be auto increment value, increases every time we find overlapping or route quality info is changed while we are processing the route.

Comment: To explain the real-life problem better:

You have two routes (Route A and Route B) from point X to point Y, sections of the routes are the same in both routes, but we have some sections which are different in Route A and in Route B. Let's say Route A is having a better quality part of the route than Route B. I want to have all sections divided by route quality and forks of the route.